# Issue with Follow Path

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, objects

I was working on a car animation, initially object wasn't following path so
I realised it had something to do with location.

Now, after trying everything, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> etc, my object is following a part weirdly. It follows it halfway and then it does not. there is a blue dotted line connected to it. I tried various combinations but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: this question was asked a lot of times. Maybe it would be good to search here for follow path. Normally you don't have the same origin point of curve + object, which causes problems.

Comment: yes I know, i searched through google but it still did not solve my issue.